# How can I make High Availability in HP-UX?

Tags: high-availability, hp-ux

We have a HP UX11 and our ERP software is running on Oracle. Now we want to buy another server hardware, and want to configure High Availability between this two. I don't want to install HP-UX manually on the new server, but I want the same OS and configuration as on the old, with incremental backup all the time.

Is there any way to do this, without any extra hardware?

Comment: What kind of HA?   HP sell something called MC/Serviceguard.  Is that what you have purchased?

Comment: another possibility might be using oracles rac for ha.

Comment: You really should talk to your HP service rep about this. There are several ways of fixing it, including using your first server as a template for the second so that you won't have to install the new one from scratch, but it's a large area which can't really be described well in a QA-site like this one.

Answer (score 1):

You do HA in HP/UX using Serviceguard or Veritas Cluster.

There is no software to automatically install the OS, configure cluster, define backups and all the things a sysadmin is supposed to do.

You don't need extra hardware except for heartbeat and standby interfaces.